# Didn't get correct return of AsyncStorage.getItem()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I've try to get value from key in AsyncStorage with sync function and try to print on console.log() command the value is correct on my expectation, but when i make an if with ternary it getting error like this.

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{_40,_65,_55,_72)

Here part code of navigator react-native

```
Guest:{
screen:MainScreen,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerLeft:
          (async () => {
              const login = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLogin");
              (login == null) ?
              <Text></Text>
              :
              <Icon
                style={{ paddingLeft: 10, color: '#ffffff', }}
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                name="menu"
                size={30}
              />
          })

       ,
    headerTransparent:true,
 })
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `headerLeft` function returns Promise, as it is `async`

But `headerLeft` had to return React.Element i guess.

So better to remove async there and create separate component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const getLogin = async(setLogin) => {
  const login = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLogin');
  setLogin(login);
}

export const HeaderLeft = ({navigation}) => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getLogin(setLogin);
  }, []);
  return (login == null)
    ? <Text/>
    : <Icon
        style={{ paddingLeft: 10, color: '#ffffff', }}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        name="menu"
        size={30}
      />
}
```

and use like

```
...
headerLeft: <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation}/>
....
```

Comment: Works, almost forgot to clear AsyncStorage. But there's little problem i can't pass navigation props, have try using <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} />

Comment: @Alfian i just added {navigation} to function props, you can try

Answer (score 0):

Create  component for  header left  with state of what you get from storage and push  navigation as prop.
On async componentWillMount  of component get async  from storage and update the state.

```
 Guest:{
screen:MainScreen,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
 headerLeft:<MyHeaderLeft navigation={navigation}/>.....
```

Comment: Have you write example code?  i've try write still don't get it